# Rasterise vector into raster mask

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I have world oceans vector layer in .shp format. 
It looks like this.
[image: Ocean vector]
This vector has only one feature, which represents world ocean. 
I need to create raster mask with 1 - ocean, and 0 - land. 
When I try Rasterize, as output I have fully black raster image. 
Then I have tried to create new numeric field
[image: Fields]
and use this field for rasterizing, but QGIS doesn`t see this new field.
[image: Rasterize]

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Could you add `-ot BYTE` in the `gdal_translate` box (by clicking on the pencil icon) and see if it changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the rasterize option, you have to edit (click on the pencil icon) the code, what you are looking for is the "burn" option of the gdal_rasterize parameter;
you should erase the "-a WHATEVER_FIELD" argument, and replace it with "-burn 1"
choose your "resolution" with either of these:
"-ts" is raster size in pixels
"-tr" is raster resolution in map units

```
gdal_rasterize -burn 1 -tr 1.0 1.0 -l your_layer D:/your_file.shp D:/your_file.tif
```

from gdal.org:
*"-burn value: A fixed value to burn into a band for all objects. A list of -burn options can be supplied, one per band being written to."*